# Alternatives to deleteOnExit

Tags: java

I want to delete some files after a certain a time say once every day.Is using deleteOnExit() for this a good option ? Any other suggestions ?

I have some flash content which render its state by reading from some xml files stored inside web server root.These xmls are created on the fly.Now I want to delete these files.It would be better if I can manage this using java

Comment: 1. DeleteOnExit only runs at JVM exit
2. It can lead to huge memory issues, because it is storing a huge cache of these in memory.
3. Could you elaborate exactly where these are being stored, what they are being used for, multithreading issues thereof [a problem with CRON], etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
java.io.File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix);
```

Let the temp file management for that operating system determine the policy for destroying files.

Comment: This works unless you are running on Windows whose policy on temp files is "do nothing".

Comment: I have downvoted your suggestion because there is no temp file management in many OSs. For example on Windows, running on Tomcat, this all goes to Tomcat\temp, not even %TEMP%. On Linux, yes, it typically goes to a /tmp subdir.

Comment: Windows has temp file management, if Tomcat chooses NOT to use it, it doesn't mean that it doesn't exist.  If you don't know that windows has temp file management, pray tell, why do you know it's controlled by the %TEMP% variable?

Comment: There's no MANAGEMENT of %TEMP%. Please cite a link.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would write a script that goes through your directory to delete files that meet your criteria (24 hours old, for instance) and run it via a cron job. I would probably have it run at a time when server load is lowest.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely avoid File.deleteOnExit. I had an [issue](http://nineofclouds.blogspot.com/2013/08/pdf-service-memory-leaks.html) where I was calling that multiple times per API call. Basically, it appends the file to a list of files to clean up on exit. The JVM never exited, since it was running in a web context. So, I had a memory leak of a bunch of files hanging around forever. It's much better to set up a cronjob or just delete the file after you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with deleteOnExit() is that if your application crashes the files are left forever. I would run a thread to clean the temp directory (except for the open files) periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) to schedule operations in Java. You could either scan the directory for files older than 24 hours on a recurring schedule, or create a new job for each file that runs 24 hours later.